# Cast va_list to pointer, then increment it

Tags: pointers, casting, variadic-functions

There is a bug in the compiler I'm using (Codesourcery for ARM) that breaks va_arg(), and I'm trying to do a work around. In this case, 'ap' is a simple pointer to a list of 32 bit and 64 bit arguments. The compiler bug is that va_arg() is broken, and will sometimes return incorrect values.

I can cast the va_list to a pointer of arbitrary type and use it to pick off values on the list:

```
void foo(va_list ap)
{
    int32_t  ival;
    double   dval;

    ival = *(int32_t*)&ap;
    dval = *(double*)&ap);
}
```

However, how can I pre or post increment 'ap' as the cast type?

For instance both of these give an error:

```
(int32_t*)&ap++;
++(int32_t*)&ap.
```

Can a real 'C' guru give me a hand? I've got a solution which works using unions to manipulate the pointer, but I'd like a more "c-worthy" method...

Comment: Which exact version of the compiler are you using? How do you invoke it? What optimization flags, etc...

Comment: I hope your embedded product is a non-important gadget (and not something really useful, like an air conditioning system) and that I won't buy or use it. I'm scared by seeing the (IMHO quite unprofessional) behavior "I don't mind about *undefined behavior*; it worked once for me so should be ok for others..."

Comment: Actually, it won't be undefined. The fix is the result of analysing the assembly code generated by the compiler when marshalling arguments on the va_list and when picking values off the va_list. The va_arg() macro generated code that incorrectly calculated an address. So, if you know how parameters are marshalled, you know how they should be retrieved. Unless we change compilers (and if the compiler behaves differently), there will be no problem. QED.

Comment: But in a couple of months, with an updated product, you *will* slightly change your code and the compiler.... So I am scared (not to mention that I am not confident in the quality of the rest of the code).

Comment: I'm not suggesting this fix should be adopted by others, btw. This seems to be a relatively unusual problem affecting some ARM implementations. And, I'm not really a programmer, but I play one on TV...

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, this is not a compiler issue at all. The problem was caused by the stack pointer NOT being on an 8 byte boundary. It is fixed by modifying the load script to use 8 byte alignment for the stack. I should add that this project is using the NutOS; a very useful piece of code.

With the stock load script, the stack pointer was loaded (sometimes, not always) with a value that was not 8 byte aligned.

My ARM9 Linux platform does NOT have this issue, though the parameter marshalling and va_arg() code is the same as for the ARM7 compiler.

I noticed that when a function is called, the compiler loads the stack pointer with a value it believes will result in an 8 byte alignment. This results in r0-r3 being 8 byte aligned. With 8 byte alignment, the va_arg() arithmetic works.

I know this doesn't answer my question. I did work out a solution that involved unions, and interestingly enough, what you would think would be extra code ended up being optimized out. So, using unions to manipulate the va_list didn't really add much overhead.

Thanks to all for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that `va_list` is castable to a pointer (it might be implemented thru compiler magic involving several registers or words).

You should only use the macros documented in [stdarg(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html), that is `va_start`, `va_end` and `va_arg` (and perhaps `va_copy`).

Your code is by definition non-portable and buggy, it triggers an [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To increment `ap` use only `va_arg(ap, int32_t)` etc...;

BTW, you could download a fresh version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (i.e. 4.8.1 today, september 18th 2013) and compile it from the source code (perhaps as a cross-compiler). It might have solved the compiler bug you have got.

Comment: va_start(), va_copy(), and va_end() all work. The problem is that va_arg() is broken, and sometimes gives incorrect results. Casting 'ap' to some type to GET a value works; my problem is how to code an increment or decrement operation.

Comment: Yes, the code is non portable. That's OK, it's an embedded device using an AT91SAM7X processor. You just gave me an idea, though, thanks. I'll try using va_arg() to just increment...

Comment: What makes you think that an undefined behavior bug (which may trigger again with a slightly different compiler, or optimization options, ...) is ok for embedded processors....? !!

Comment: It's OK because this is a dedicated application; the compiler won't change, and we can verify that what we use will work properly. BTW, can't use va_arg() to increment as it gets optimized away.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the cast nor the & operator return assignable values (aka "L-values" that can be on the left hand side of an equals sign). You could try:

```
int ival;
void * pap = &ap;
ival = *(int32_t*)pap;
pap += sizeof(int32_t);
```

But, as the previous answer says, va_list implementations will vary between platforms and any workaround is not likely to be portable. If you decide to go ahead with a workaround, at least be sure to include a unit test for va_list so you will know if it breaks.